# Is there any case where [self retain] is valid?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Reading source code of my current project, I see:

```
[self retain]
```

in one class, in its `init` method.

I don't understand exactly the reason.
Reading memory management rules from Apple, I don't see anything about this, and I don't see any hypothetical `[self release]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object is asserting ownership of itself when it is initialised.  The only reason I can see that this might be useful is if the object needs to guarantee its own existence until some event has happened.  For example, it might run a timer and then release itself when the timer expires.

If it's not documented and there is no corresponding release, it's probably a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Best guess is that the person writing the code had a retain error and this was a "quick fix" around the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly some classes use the self-retain to avoid pre-mature releasing. I would say it's not exactly best practice, but if you know the rules of the game (in this case Obj-C) you can break them (sometimes).

Comment: Not entirely. You're effectively handing over the alert to UIKit when you call `show` and then you don't want it any more so you `release` it. No doubt behind the scenes in UIKit something is holding onto it (for example it'll have been added to the view hierarchy so its superview will be retaining it for a start).

Comment: Right... the app window is probably the retainer.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be probably an error, usually it's not up to the object to retain himself.

I see only one special case: delegate and notification, where you have to be much more careful about your life cycle, but even if this case, release/retain should not be done in the object itself.

**Note to Erick:**

In case of UIAlert, you can release it before it has been destroyed because the view has been but in the view hiercarchy, and then referenced. So the view will be automatically destroyed when it will be removed from the view hierarchy

Comment: When is destroyed? Perhaps after replying to delegate, just after user press a button, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

It's not wrong to retain `self`. But seeing it in an `init` method sounds suspicious. I can't think of a good example of where that would be a good thing to do. Also though, with ARC, you can't even do that so you'd have to think of a better way of doing things. In general, if an object is required to be alive then there would be another object that is holding onto it. Self retaining objects are prone to errors where they will never be released.

Answer (score -3):

if you have some object, it's like it have healts/ lives. when you created it , it have one live. and. function 'retain' increasing his number of lives +1, release function decreasing his number of lives -1, dealloc decreasing too, alloc increasing

Comment: This is definitely NOT what the OP asked. The question is how does `[self retain]` works instead of normal `retain`.